# Relatório do Jasper Report não Abrindo

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Estou com um problema em um relatório gerado pelo Jasper Report.
Criei uma tela com parâmetros do relatório que ao pressionar o botão chama o método abaixo.

```
public void imprimir() {
    try {
        RpFolhaDePagamentoDAO dao = new RpFolhaDePagamentoDAO();
        List resultado = dao.gerarSQL(folhaDePagamento, dataInicial, dataFinal, eventosSelecionados, funcionariosSelecionados);

        JRBeanCollectionDataSource colecao = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(resultado);

        String caminho = Faces.getRealPath("/reports/folhaDePagamento.jasper");

        Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
        parametros.put("dataInicial", dataInicial);
        parametros.put("dataFinal", dataFinal);

        JasperPrint relatorio = JasperFillManager.fillReport(caminho, parametros, colecao);
        byte[] buffer = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(relatorio);
        Faces.sendFile(buffer, "folhaDePagamento.pdf", false);
    } catch (JRException | IOException erro) {
        String mensagemCapturada = TratadorDeErros.capturarMensagem(erro);
        Messages.addGlobalWarn("Erro ao emitir relatorio da Folha de Pagamento " + mensagemCapturada);
        erro.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Ao final não dá erro de execução, o SQL me retorna informações, mas não é aberto a aba com o relatório em PDF.

Tenho vários outros relatórios que seguem o mesmo padrão e neste tive problema.
Detalhe: este relatório foi criado em uma nova versão do Eclipse e do JasperSoftStudio 6.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Segue exemplo da solução que dei para o botão da chamada do método.

```
<p:commandButton title="Print" actionListener="#{rpFolhaDePagamentoBean.imprimir}" ajax="false" onclick="this.form.target='_blank'" icon="fa fa-print" />
```